# Unity - Materials array back to original object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in Unity I'm currently making some select/ hover function so that the color of an object changes if you hover over it and change back when the mouse is no longer over the object. So the problem is putting the materials back.

I have an object with lots of children/grandchildren/sub children(?). So first I get the child objects through a foreach loop. Then I get the materials, also through a foreach loop, in an array called 'baseMaterials'. In my update function i change the objects material to a 'hoverMaterial'.

But my question is how do I change the 'hoverMaterial' back to the 'baseMaterials' ?

```
private void Awake()
{
    // Get children objects with renderers, skip empty objects without renderers
    List<GameObject> objectChildrenList = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (child.GetComponent<Renderer>())
            objectChildrenList.Add(child.gameObject);

        foreach (Transform grandChild in child)
        {
            objectChildrenList.Add(grandChild.gameObject);
        }
    }
    objectChildren = objectChildrenList.ToArray();

    // get from children objects the color 
    if (objectName.transform.childCount > 0)
    {
        List<Material> objectColors = new List<Material>();
        foreach (GameObject objects in objectChildren)
        {
            var objectMat = objects.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
            foreach (Material m in objectMat)
            {
                objectColors.Add(m);
            }
        }
        baseMaterials = objectColors.ToArray();
    } else {
        baseMaterial = objectName.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (gameManager.selectedObject != this.gameObject)
    {
        if (mouseOver)
        {                
            if (objectName.transform.childCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (Transform child in transform)
                {
                    if (child.GetComponent<Renderer>())
                        child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = hoverMaterial;

                    foreach (Transform grandChild in child)
                    {
                        grandChild.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = hoverMaterial;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                objectName.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = hoverMaterial;
            }
        } else {
            if (objectName.transform.childCount > 0) {
                // Put baseMaterials back
            } else {
                objectName.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = baseMaterial;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You could store each default material in a dictionary using the child object's hashcode as the key, then set them from the dictionary. You could also store a default material in each of the child object classes and just call SetToDefault() to return the material to its default.

Comment: In your `Awake()` method, do you intended to add the `child` twice if it has a `Renderer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is using a dictionary, afaik. The reason for this is that if you save the Materials as a list, the number of GameObjects in the scene might change by the time you stop hovering and the list you saved won't line up with the actual materials of the GameObjects anymore. So you need to know which materials belong to which Renderer/GameObject. A dictionary gives you that.

So I'd use a `Dictionary<Renderer, List<Material>>`. When you start hovering you iterate all of the GameObjects with renderers you want to change and save them in the dictionary. Then you change the materials. When the hover stops, you iterate through the dictionary and set the materials back.

---

Note that if all you want to change is the color then using [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) is a much better idea. You can use [MaterialPropertyBlock.SetColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.SetColor.html), you just need to know what the color property is named in the shader. It's generally `_Color`, you can check by looking at the material in the Inspector in debug mode. The advantage of using MaterialPropertyBlock is that you won't generate an additional draw call. It's just an all around better way of doing it.